# How to escape and loop with python inside curly brackets

Tags: python-3.x

For example, I have a list items=["a", "b", "c"]. And I want to escape and loop those in curly brackets for the requests body.

```
{
  ...
  "files": {
    for index,item in enumerate(items):
      "index1": "item1",
      "idex2": "item2",

  },
  ...
}
```

My wanted results is:

```
{
  ...
  "files": {
      "0": "a",
      "1": "b",
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `{str(index): item for index, item in enumerate(["a", "b"])}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much is clear from you question, but is this what you want:

```
items = ["a", "b"]
results = {"files": {}}
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    results['files'][str(index)] = item
print (results)
```

Output:

```
{
    'files': {
        '0': 'a',
        '1': 'b'
    }
}
```